# Why wont my foreach file container loop?

Tags: ssis

I have two foreach file containers in a package.

Both has the same settings except they have different names:
One is called "Foreach Availability File" and the other is called "Foreach Communication File".

The first container "availability" goes through 1 iteration (I can see this through breakpoints) the second "communication" does not.

Again both of these containers are identical aside from name.

I tested this by retrying after renaming "Foreach Communication File" to "Foreach Comm File" and suddenly the container works.

Can anyone tell me why this happened?

Craig

Comment: Are the containers triggered in parallel or in serial?

Comment: There are a lot of places for settings to hide.  I am going to bet they are not identical.  Try and delete the problematic loop and start from scratch.

Comment: did that. Same problem.

I had a broken foreach container and I fixed it by changing its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit repro steps to connect.microsoft.com - they can tell you why if it is repro-able.

Comment: Did you submit a connect item?  I'd try the microsoft forums as well - they have employees which will make sure questions get answered.